# Installing Acrobat fails

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I try to install and run acrobat reader on Ubuntu. But it fails:

```
guettli@p15:~$ acrordrdc

Installing application..
Running hook '/snap/acrordrdc/62/sommelier/hooks/pre-install'
------------------------------------------------------
winetricks latest version check update disabled
------------------------------------------------------
Executing mkdir -p /home/guettli/snap/acrordrdc/common
Using winetricks 20210206-next - sha256sum: 10d6518a92035512f9d5a20fcd8eab0b15dedb8a3c42eb7b6ad703ce909482a2 with wine-6.0.2 and WINEARCH=win32
Executing w_do_call mspatcha
Executing mkdir -p /home/guettli/snap/acrordrdc/common
Executing load_mspatcha 
Executing cd /home/guettli/snap/acrordrdc/common/.cache/winetricks/win2ksp4
Downloading http://x3270.bgp.nu/download/specials/W2KSP4_EN.EXE to /home/guettli/snap/acrordrdc/common/.cache/winetricks/win2ksp4
--2021-12-02 15:15:30--  http://x3270.bgp.nu/download/specials/W2KSP4_EN.EXE
Resolving x3270.bgp.nu (x3270.bgp.nu)... 147.28.0.53
Connecting to x3270.bgp.nu (x3270.bgp.nu)|147.28.0.53|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 135477136 (129M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘W2KSP4_EN.EXE’

W2KSP4_EN.EXE                               1%[>                                                                                     ]   1,74M  --.-KB/s    in 69s     

2021-12-02 15:16:40 (25,8 KB/s) - Read error at byte 1828462/135477136 (Connection timed out). Retrying.

--2021-12-02 15:16:41--  (try: 2)  http://x3270.bgp.nu/download/specials/W2KSP4_EN.EXE
Connecting to x3270.bgp.nu (x3270.bgp.nu)|147.28.0.53|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 206 Partial Content
Length: 135477136 (129M), 133648674 (127M) remaining [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘W2KSP4_EN.EXE’

W2KSP4_EN.EXE                               3%[+=>                                                                                   ]   4,58M  --.-KB/s    in 3m 25s  

2021-12-02 15:20:06 (14,2 KB/s) - Read error at byte 4801661/135477136 (Connection timed out). Retrying.

--2021-12-02 15:20:08--  (try: 3)  http://x3270.bgp.nu/download/specials/W2KSP4_EN.EXE
Connecting to x3270.bgp.nu (x3270.bgp.nu)|147.28.0.53|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 206 Partial Content
Length: 135477136 (129M), 130675475 (125M) remaining [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘W2KSP4_EN.EXE’

W2KSP4_EN.EXE                               6%[+++=>                                                                                 ]   8,96M  --.-KB/s    in 3m 4s   

2021-12-02 15:23:13 (24,4 KB/s) - Read error at byte 9394860/135477136 (Connection timed out). Giving up.

------------------------------------------------------
warning: Checksum for /home/guettli/snap/acrordrdc/common/.cache/winetricks/win2ksp4/W2KSP4_EN.EXE did not match, retrying download
------------------------------------------------------
Executing cd /home/guettli/snap/acrordrdc/common/.cache/winetricks/win2ksp4
Downloading https://web.archive.org/web/2000/http://x3270.bgp.nu/download/specials/W2KSP4_EN.EXE to /home/guettli/snap/acrordrdc/common/.cache/winetricks/win2ksp4
--2021-12-02 15:23:13--  https://web.archive.org/web/2000/http://x3270.bgp.nu/download/specials/W2KSP4_EN.EXE
Resolving web.archive.org (web.archive.org)... 207.241.237.3
Connecting to web.archive.org (web.archive.org)|207.241.237.3|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 FOUND
Location: https://web.archive.org/web/20180719184830/http://x3270.bgp.nu/download/specials/W2KSP4_EN.EXE [following]
--2021-12-02 15:23:15--  https://web.archive.org/web/20180719184830/http://x3270.bgp.nu/download/specials/W2KSP4_EN.EXE
Reusing existing connection to web.archive.org:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘W2KSP4_EN.EXE’

W2KSP4_EN.EXE                                 [                                          <=>                                         ]  18,68M  28,4KB/s    in 9m 57s  

2021-12-02 15:33:30 (32,1 KB/s) - Read error at byte 19590034 (Success).Retrying.

--2021-12-02 15:33:31--  (try: 2)  https://web.archive.org/web/20180719184830/http://x3270.bgp.nu/download/specials/W2KSP4_EN.EXE
Connecting to web.archive.org (web.archive.org)|207.241.237.3|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘W2KSP4_EN.EXE’

W2KSP4_EN.EXE                                 [         <=>                                                                          ]  11,76M  24,9KB/s    in 5m 29s  

2021-12-02 15:39:21 (36,6 KB/s) - Read error at byte 19590034 (Success).Retrying.

--2021-12-02 15:39:23--  (try: 3)  https://web.archive.org/web/20180719184830/http://x3270.bgp.nu/download/specials/W2KSP4_EN.EXE
Connecting to web.archive.org (web.archive.org)|207.241.237.3|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘W2KSP4_EN.EXE’

W2KSP4_EN.EXE                                 [                                 <=>                                                  ]   9,07M  57,4KB/s    in 3m 7s   

2021-12-02 15:42:59 (49,7 KB/s) - Read error at byte 19590034 (Success).Giving up.

------------------------------------------------------
warning: Downloading https://web.archive.org/web/2000/http://x3270.bgp.nu/download/specials/W2KSP4_EN.EXE failed
------------------------------------------------------

(yad:924451): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:42:59.622: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1428:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(yad:924451): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:42:59.624: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3318:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(yad:924451): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:42:59.624: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3780:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(yad:924467): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:43:07.215: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:1428:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(yad:924467): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:43:07.217: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3318:25: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name

(yad:924467): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:43:07.217: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:3780:23: 'font-feature-settings' is not a valid property name
/snap/acrordrdc/62/sommelier/hooks/pre-install: line 53: cd: /home/guettli/snap/acrordrdc/common/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Common Files/Adobe/ARM/1.0: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'armsvc.exe': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'AdobeARM.exe': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'AdobeARMHelper.exe': No such file or directory
/snap/acrordrdc/62/sommelier/hooks/pre-install: line 57: cd: /home/guettli/snap/acrordrdc/common/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Adobe/Acrobat Reader DC/Reader/AcroCEF: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'RdrServicesUpdater.exe': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat 'RdrCEF.exe': No such file or directory
Starting application..
```

What can I do to get Acrobat?

PS: My internet connection works fine. It must be a problem on the other side.

Comment: As you can see, the download is failing repeatedly. Try again from a different internet connection. This could also be a temporary issue with the archive.org servers.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi this is no temporary failure, since it fails today, too. My connection is fine. It must be on the server side.

Comment: Please check if you can manually download the installer with the command `wget https://web.archive.org/web/2000/http://x3270.bgp.nu/download/specials/W2KSP4_EN.EXE`.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi no, wget fails, too. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it works for me. It must be some sort of network issue on your side.

Comment: Maybe you can download this file from another computer/another network, copy it to this computer, and modify `/snap/acrordrdc/62/sommelier/hooks/pre-install` to use it.